# Function returning the JTable by taking parameter as a Component's Name

Tags: java, swing, jtable, components

```
public JTable getTable(String Component_name)
    {
        JTable table=new JTable();
    //in this function i want to search all the JTables that have been created on runtime! 
    //and then i want to return one JTable by the name "Component_Name"//

        return table;
    }
```

This is how i want my function to be ; i came up with a solution of creating a new class of Components having private JTable table and private String name, But still problem comes up at searching JTables by name.

Comment: What do you mean by *JTable by the name "Component_Name"*? `JTable` does not have a name.

Comment: if we set each JTables name.  by Component.setName();

Comment: You can achieve this by using a data structure that stores the data with key-value pairs (ie. `HashMap`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sucessful answer !!

I created
        private ArrayList List=new ArrayList();

and in my ActionListener::

```
 AddTableMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
                //This method will be called whenever you click the button. 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
               Table table=new Table();

              JTable.setName("Table"+count);

              AddT(table);                               // Table List 
    }
```

where

```
  public ArrayList<JTable> getTable()
  {
        return List;
  }

 public void AddT(JTable tl)
 {
     if(tl.getName()!=null)
     {getTable().add(tl);}
     else return;
 }
```

Now i have a List of all JTables that now i can fetch by names implementation as follows::

```
JTable one= new JTable();
  JTable two= new JTable();
  ComboBoxModel combo = comboBox.getModel();

 for(JPanel t: getTable())
  {  
       if(combo.getSelectedItem().equals(t.getName()))
       {
          one=t;
       }
  }
```

Comment: Consider `List<JTable> list = new ArrayList<JTable>()`; also, use conventional Java variable names; code to the `List` interface; use generic types consistently.

Answer (score 2):

Combining the suggestions of @Alican Ozgoren, @mKorbel and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10623134/230513), you can construct a `Map<String, NamedModel>` for rapid access to a `TableModel` by name.

```
public TableModel getTable(String name) {
    return map.get(name);
}
```

The example below *replaces* the model of a single `JTable`, while the other [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10623134/230513) displays multiple tables.

[image: Test image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16611982/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10623134/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private static final int N = 25;
    private DefaultComboBoxModel dcbm = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    private JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(dcbm);
    private JTable table = new JTable(1, 1);
    private Map<String, NamedModel> map = new HashMap<String, NamedModel>();

    public TableModel getTable(String name) {
        return map.get(name);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            String name = "Table " + String.valueOf(i);
            NamedModel model = new NamedModel(name);
            map.put(name, model);
            dcbm.addElement(model);
        }
        combo.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                TableModel model = (TableModel) combo.getSelectedItem();
                table.setModel(model);
            }
        });
        f.add(combo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.add(table);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class NamedModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        private String name;

        public NamedModel(String name) {
            super(1, 1);
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return name + ", " + row + ", " + col;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> This is how i want my function to be ; i came up with a solution of
>   creating a new class of Components having private JTable table and
>   private String name, But still problem comes up at searching JTables
>   by name.

agree, very good desing, make me sence in the case ...

```
public JTable getTable(String Component_name)
```

could be

```
public JTable getTable(myTableModel, arrays implemented in JTables API)
```

not to declaring (overloading there) Components name, this could be inside methods returns JTable, still I can't found reason for that

Comment: how do i search then ? can you please reform my above function ?

Comment: still I miss this requirement, this JTable is always accesisible in current components hierarchy from current JVM, whats reson to hold its name, for why reason, I'm hope that you didn't create a bunch of JTable on runtime, that one to replace the another one, then answer is about re_use one JTable, with only one TableModel

Comment: i have an interface that onclick "Create" Button puts JTables on the JFrame; and on mentioning two  JTable's name it draws line between them

Comment: then reason posting and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), [can be based on](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A714968+[jtable]+TableSelectionGood)