# JComboBox custom editor JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, cellrenderer

I want to add Jtable to JComboBox Editor, so when i select the ComboBox the JTable show up.

I can't use table.removeActionListener() and table.addActionListener(). we new  functions

table.addAncestorListener( addAncestorListener listener) and

table.removeAncestorListener(addAncestorListener listener)

her is my code so far,

```
public class CustomComboEditor implements ComboBoxEditor {
    private JTable table  ;
    public CustomComboEditor() {
        table = new JTable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addActionListener(ActionListener l) {

      // there is no addActionListener(l) for table

    }

    @Override
    public Component getEditorComponent() {
        return table ; 
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem() {
        return table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn());
    }

    @Override
    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener l) {

        // there is no removeActionListener(l);for table
    }

    @Override
    public void selectAll() {
        table.selectAll();

    }

    @Override
    public void setItem(Object anObject) {
        return ; 

    }

}
```

her is an image illustrates what i want exactly

[combobox table editor http://im47.gulfup.com/ECk9HK.png](http://im47.gulfup.com/ECk9HK.png)

Comment: Here's one approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14983562/1438660

Answer (score 1):

While it may be technically possible to use a `JTable` as a `ComboBoxEditor`, the result may be unwieldy. Instead, add the desired instances of your `TableModel` to the combo's `ComboBoxModel` and use `setModel()` to display the selected model in an adjacent  `JTable`. Summarized below, a complete example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16611982/230513).

[image]

```
DefaultComboBoxModel dcbm = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
private JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(dcvm);
…
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    …
    TableModel model = new YourTableModelModel(name);
    dcbm.addElement(model);
}
…
combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        TableModel model = (TableModel) combo.getSelectedItem();
        table.setModel(model);
    }
});
```